# R: how to count the number of values a row has in another data frame's (length varies)

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have two datasets:

one is the dummy dataset A indicating the existence of certain features:

```
id  a  b  c  .... x  y  z
1   1  0  0  .... 1  1  1
2   0  1  1  .... 0  0  0
    ...
```

and another data set B is the name of features in different products that has the following format:

```
  prod1  a g b z
  prod2  b d r h t j
   ...
  prod56 f e h
```

what I want to know is the number of features that each id has of each product divided by the number of total feature of a product. (Please note that each id may have features across multiple products and the number of features in each product varies).

for example, I want an output matrix with each id in a row and each product in a column and the ratio count in each cell:

```
   output:
   id  prodA prod B .... prod56
   1   2/26   1/26  .... ...
   2   1/26   1/26  .... ...
   ...
```

I know I can achieve this using loops but I am wondering if there is cleaner and faster way of doing this using data manipulation packages like dplyr, but I am not very familiar with these packages, so I would greatly appreciate any insight.

data (something like the following but the acutual length of product features may vary - here they all contain 4 features represented by 4 letters):

```
id = seq(1:10)
data = rbinom(260, 1, 0.5)
dat_mat = matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 26, data)
colnames(dat_mat) = letters[seq( from = 1, to = 26 )]
library("random")
set.seed(1234)
product = randomStrings(n=56, len=4, upperalpha=F,digits = F,
          loweralpha=TRUE, unique=TRUE, check=TRUE)
```

Comment: Are these datasets in R (please share) or in a file?

Comment: As Ott commented, could you provide your two datasets in a reproducible format? You might try formatting your two datasets as a 0/1 matrix (probably sparse) of (i) id * features and (ii) product * features and take their `?tcrossprod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something with pmatch?

```
set.seed(1)
d1 <- matrix(rbinom(4*26, 1, 0.5), 4, 26)
# just random data
colnames(d1) <- letters
d2 <- c(prod1="agbz", prod2="bdrhtj", prod3="feh", prod4="xys")
# just random data
p1s <- apply(d1, 1, function(x) letters[which(as.logical(x))])
p2s <- strsplit(d2, "")
res <- matrix("", length(p1s), length(p2s))
for(i in seq(along=p1s)) {
   s1 <- p1s[[i]]
   for(j in seq(along=p2s)) {
      s2 <- p2s[[j]]
      res[i, j] <- sum(!is.na(pmatch(s1, s2)))
   }
}
res
```

gives you

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "1"  "4"  "3"  "1" 
[2,] "1"  "2"  "1"  "1" 
[3,] "2"  "4"  "1"  "2" 
[4,] "3"  "4"  "2"  "3"
```

Note: in this approach there is no way around the double loop for
creating the output table as both datasets are transformed to lists of
character vectors.

I don't think dplyr offers much here.